# Returning a sorted Java list instead of sorting it in-place

Tags: java, sorting, collections

The Java collections API has a [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method that sorts a list in-place. Is there such a method that doesn't change the given list but returns a sorted one?

Comment: Why not copy the collection into a new one with addAll, and then sort the copy?

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in method that does that but it's a two-liner: `List copy = new ArrayList(original); Collections.sort(copy);`

Comment: I consider this as already being answered. But an aside: Imagine there was **only** a method that returns a new, sorted list. (Things like this have to be kept in mind when designing an API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 provides this via the Streams API:

```
return inputList.stream().sorted().collect(toList());
```

(I am assuming `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;`)